# Unable to set default download directory from chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have problems with setting the default download folder for chrome driver.
I found some information related to this but none of it is working. 
This is what I've tried:

```
var options = new ChromeOptionsWithPrefs();
options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
options.prefs = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                { "download.default_directory", folderName },
                { "download.prompt_for_download", false },
                { "intl.accept_languages", "nl" }};
webdriver = new ChromeDriver(chromedriver_path, options);
```

and

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", folderName);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
```

I am using chrome driver 2.9(latest one) and chrome version 33.
Also tried to set a default directory for chrome and when I start the web-driver I expect that the default directory to be change but I did not work as well.

Do you have any new idea how I can set the this default folder?

Edit: adding declaration:

```
string folderName = @"C:\Browser";
```

Comment: can we see your initialization of `folderName`

Comment: You can see in the code examples that I implement it and is not working

Comment: Oh sorry, it is like in the example you provide that was my implementation in the first place it worked like 2-4 weeks ago but now is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into trouble doing this with ChromeDriver `2.24` and Selenium `3.0`.

For me the following code worked:

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);

var downloadPrefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"default_directory", @"C:\Users\underscore\MyCustomLocation"},
    {"directory_upgrade", true}
};

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download", downloadPrefs);

return new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

Hopefully this helps anyone trying to do it now.

In case it changes in future; I verified the required format by opening my default Chrome preferences file. The location of this file can be found by browsing to `chrome://version` and opening the Preferences file at the location specified by Profile Path. This showed that the default `"download"` key has an object with these values.

I could then check the changes were applied by opening the preferences file used by the Selenium Chrome browser (again by checking the location from `chrome://version`).

#### Edit 2

---

Similarly in order to disable the inbuilt Chrome PDF Viewer which was blocking file downloads, I added the following lines to the configuration:

```
var pdfViewerPlugin = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["enabled"] = false,
    ["name"] = "Chrome PDF Viewer"
};

var pluginsList = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "plugins_list", new [] { pdfViewerPlugin } }
};

var downloadPreferences = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"default_directory", launchOptions.DownloadFolder},
    {"directory_upgrade", true}
};

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download", downloadPreferences);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins", pluginsList);
```

---

### Firefox

---

Since I wasted another hour on this today, here is the configuration for Firefox (49+) running the same version of Selenium (Note: **this won't work with GeckoDriver 0.10.0 and Selenium 3.0.0+**, GeckoDriver must be version 0.11.1):

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "GeckoBinary");

var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path);

service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", myDownloadLocation);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.downloadDir", myDownloadLocation);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", myDownloadLocation);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ContentTypes.AllTypesSingleLine);
profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

return new FirefoxDriver(service, new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = profile
}, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Where `ContentTypes.AllTypesSingleLine` is just a string containing mime types, e.g.:

```
application/pdf;application/excel;...
```

As of GeckoDriver 0.11.1 and Selenium 3.0.1 this can be simplified to:

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();

options.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", launchOptions.DownloadFolder);
options.SetPreference("browser.download.downloadDir", launchOptions.DownloadFolder);
options.SetPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", launchOptions.DownloadFolder);
options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ContentTypes.AllTypesSingleLine);
options.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
options.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
options.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

return new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```