# How to rename downloaded file using selenium c# webdriver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In my web application which has some automation process to download the files from the website. To achieve that I used selenium c# chrome driver.

Sample code snippets

```
public void Download(string name,string pass)
{
    try
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=http://192.168.5.62:8095");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory",@"C:\Temp");

        using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, options)){

            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/u[contains(text(),'Re-Submit')]")).click();
            driver.FindElementById("save").Click();                               
        }              
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {       
        Logger.LogWriter("LAS", ex, "CusDataLogic", "Download");
    }
}
```

above code (not complete code) works fine and save file properly. But I need to rename that file downloading or after download. Have any possible way to rename that file?

Edited: Please don't mark this as a duplicate. I'm asking for C#, not python. I saw that question too. but it not helped to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium, find out when a download has completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338897/python-selenium-find-out-when-a-download-has-completed)

Comment: @BishalGautam Please don't mark this as a duplicate. I'm asking for C#, not python. I saw that question too. but it not helped to me

Comment: @Sachith the idea is the same regardless of language used -- watch the download directory and process the files when they appear.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns How can I do it. please help me to solve it

Answer (score 1):

watching directory is not always good, because sometime saved filename is different than filename in URL.

go to chrome download page and loop until all download complete, you can see below how to select special element `#shadow-root` with CSS selector

```
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, options)))
{
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/u[contains(text(),'Re-Submit')]")).click();
    driver.FindElementById("save").Click();

    // wait 5 second until download started
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    // Go to chrome download page
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://downloads/");
    string oldName = "";
    bool downloadcomplete = false;
    string cssNames = "downloads-manager /deep/ downloads-item /deep/ [id='name']";
    string cssDlProgress = "downloads-manager /deep/ downloads-item /deep/ [class*='show-progress']";

    while (!downloadcomplete)
    {
        var progressElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(cssDlProgress));
        // check until no download progress bar
        if (progressElements.Count() == 0)
        {
            oldName = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(cssNames)).Text;
            downloadcomplete = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // download still in progress, wait.
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    // download complete
    // remove downloaded file
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("downloads-manager /deep/ downloads-item /deep/ [id='remove']")).Click();
    // rename
    File.Move(@"C:\Temp\" + oldName, @"C:\Temp\newname.ext");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ewwink , I have a problem. suppose this download method called inside for loop. each time file download based on parameters until loop false. so each time your logic calls. how to handle that? I need to rename file one by one. and please tell me how to rename file using your code, I'm confused with that

Comment: I updated my code. suppose this method called inside `forloop`. based on name and password file will be downloaded. so how to rename each file after download

Comment: According to my code files download properly to this path `C:\Temp`. But not showing downloaded file in `chrome://downloads/` menu

Comment: oh I forgot that, call it in your Download method and click `id="remove"` to clear download list

Comment: for download directory, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536907/

Comment: Can you update your answer and please give me example (to rename the file)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain why download files not appear in `chrome://downloads/` menu? But downloaded to `options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory",@"C:\Temp");` location. But not appear in `chrome://downloads/` menu

Comment: it need `sleep` after clicking `save` element.

Comment: I added thread after this line `driver.FindElementById("save").Click();`
like this `Thread.Sleep(3000);` But not shownig downloaded files in chrome menu

Comment: try increase up to 10 second

Comment: I tried your code. But in this line `File.Move(@"C:\Temp\" + oldName, @"C:\Temp\newname.ext");` error occured. `Could not find file 'C:\Temp\'.` reason was `oldName ` not set file name properly. `oldName` value shows as `" "` .I think this line  `oldName = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(cssNames)).Text;`  not working properly

Comment: is download started and showing in `chrome://downloads/` ?

Comment: In my target website file download start after big process. 3 windows popuped and final window star file download process. downloaded file shows that last popuoped windows's menu.  Its ok now, but downloaded file name cant identify in your code

Answer (score 0):

The Snippet Below Will wait Until File downloaded Then return FilePath I Wrote this as an extension method :

```
public static string GetDonwloadedFileName(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    js.ExecuteScript("window.open()");
    var allWinowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
    foreach (var winHandle in allWinowHandles)
    {
        //Switch to second window
        if (!winHandle.Equals(driver.CurrentWindowHandle))
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
        }
    }
    // navigate to chrome downloads
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://downloads");
    IJavaScriptExecutor downloadWindowExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    // Wait for Download till 100% completion
    double percentageProgress = (double)0;
    while (percentageProgress != 100)
    {
        try
        {
            percentageProgress = (long)downloadWindowExecutor.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress').value");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    string fileTitle = (string)downloadWindowExecutor.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#show').getAttribute('title')");
    downloadWindowExecutor.ExecuteScript("window.close()");
    return fileTitle;
}
```

Then You can use file Path to rename it to whatever you need